# Backbonejs routing casesensitivity issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I am using backbonejs router and it seems that routing is not working for opposite case of route which has been configured.

```
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'project(/)(/index)': 'showProjects',
        'project/:id': 'showProjectEdit'
    }
});
```

Works for http://www.test.com:53895/project 
But not working when P is in uppercase http://www.test.com:53895/Project

The version which i am using is 1.1.2. Please help!

Comment: But URLs are case-sensitive; http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html. In any case, there are several resources searchable both on SO and the web in general describing how to circumvent the spec, e.g., https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/848.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make the route to be case insensitive by adding the 'i' attribute to the return value of _routeToRegExp function in backbonejs library.

```
_routeToRegExp: function (route) {
      var namedParam    = /:\w+/g;
      var splatParam    = /\*\w+/g;
      var escapeRegExp  = /[-[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g;    

      route = route.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&')
                   .replace(namedParam, '([^\/]+\/?)')
                   .replace(splatParam, '(.*?)');

      return new RegExp('^' + route + '$');
      /*
       * Note: If you would like case insensitivity, 
       *       add the "i" attribute to the return
       * return new RegExp('^' + route + '$', 'i');
       */
}
```

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/848

Thanks Dave!